# java - definir una método boolean

Tags: java, booleano

Quiero definir un método tipo `boolean` que representa la función PLAY (de una película o de un CD por ejemplo)

La interfaz `PLAYABLE` contiene varios métodos:

- `isPlaying`: devuelve el atributo `playing`
- `play`: método que cambia el estado del atributo. Si está en valor `true` cambia a `false` y viceversa. Si cambia `true`, debe mostrar un mensaje por pantalla: `is playing!` y si cambia a `false` mostrará: `is stopped!`

El diagrama UML es el siguiente:

```
    <<interface >> 
       Playable
    ----------------
    * +isPlaying(): boolean*
    * +play()*
```

Esto es lo que he planteado, pero estoy seguro de que tengo varios errores pero no sé cómo plantearlo.

```
public interface Playable {
    boolean isPlaying();

    default boolean play(){
        if (playing == false){
            playing = true;
            System.out.println("is playing!");
        }
        if (playing == true){
            playing = false;
            System.out.println("is stopped!");
        }
    }

}
```

Esta interfaz se relaciona con otras clases (película y audio), ambas contienen la inicialización de la variable `playing` como  `private boolean playing = false;` (además de otros métodos que no afectan a la duda)

Quería saber si es correcto mi planteamiento.

Gracias.

Comment: en tu clase no está definiudo `playing` lo que te debería de dar error. Te sugiero además especificar la versión de java con la que trabajas.